# Can we use 2 Denormalizer one for read and the other for elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, cqrs

Can i use 2 Denormalizer:

1st DN for "read" for my web application

2nd DN for search engine

Or

One DN for both read and search for my web application

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You mean process the content of a field in different ways? Once optimized for full-text-search, once for display and/or sorting purposes? Please refine your question.

Comment: Yes thats exactly what i mean DN1 optimized for full-text-search, DN2 for display and/or sorting purposes

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes

You should only have one command bound to a command handler but you can and often will have multiple event handlers/denomarmalisers per event.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your field mapping, Elasticsearch will preprocess your Strings prior to storing them in a field indoor index.

If you want to use a field for full-text-search, you need to map it to a field of type `text`. By doing so, your string will get processed by the `Standard Analyzer` (unless you specify a different analyzer for that field) when writing your string into the index.

If, on the other hand, you want to use your field mainly for sorting, exact filtering or running analysis on it (e.g. how many distinct values, what are min & max values, what are the top 10 values, etc) you need to map int to a field of type `keyword` to make sure the String is preserved as is, when writing into the index. But be aware, that only for displaying the original string, you don't need to store it as a `keyword`-field, as Elasticsearch already has a copy of the original string in its `source`-field.

The good thing: you don't need to decide on one or the other, Elasticsearch allows you to to store a field you send to it in multiple ways, by using so-called `multi-fields`. This is also the default implementation for Strings (as Elasticsearch does not know what you will use a String field for).

**Example Mapping for my_field**

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "my_field": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": { 
            "type":  "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(source: [Elasticsearch reference: Multi-Fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html))

**Referencing my_field**

- when displaying or searching in a field, simply refer to it by `my_field`.
- for exact match queries, sorting or analytics/aggregation purposes, refer to the field as `my_field.keyword`